# I do not know how I can compare password[i] and 65 and 90

Tags: c#, char

I wrote a code a few days ago, but now I do not get how it functions.

I researched already in the internet but found nothing that matches or is even similar to my code.

```cs
public int capitalLetters(string password)
{
    int capitalLetters = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++)
    {
        if(password[i] >= 65 && password[i] <= 90) 
        {
            capitalLetters++;
        }
    }
    return capitalLetters;
}
```

I get the right results, but I dont know how it works.
It gives the Number of capital letters used in the string.

Comment: www.asciitable.com

Comment: You should use [char.IsUpper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isupper) instead of comparing against 'A' (65) and 'Z' (90) which captures only a minuscule amount of all capital letters that exist. At least use `'A'` for 65 and `'Z'` for 90 which makes your intention much more clearer and readable.

Comment: I agree to the opinion of @ckuri and therefore would say that this code does not work. It works only for ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what going on here implicit conversion on character type into integer type. That's probably the part which you are sceptical about.

`if(password[i] >= 65 && password[i] <= 90)`
That line of code checks whether the character at the index of I in the string named "Password" has a value between 65 and 90, which if you check the ASCII values of characters is where all capital letters are located. The ASCII values of capital letters coincide with the implicit conversion on char type into int type and the number of capital letter is counted by your counter.

Comment: Hey so i dont have to convert anything i can just directly Conpare those ?

Comment: @CodeLover yes you can do the following:   `if (a>='A' && a<= 'Z')`  This will find all the capital letters